# Load data for RNN

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, neural-network, theano, deep-learning

In RNN training examples, I noticed input data and target data are all 3-dimension arrays, and need to define time-step delay between input and output.

```
input_seqs = np.zeros((num_batches, num_time_steps, batch_size), dtype=floatX)
target_seqs = np.zeros((num_batches, num_time_steps, batch_size), dtype=floatX)
target_seqs[0:-1, :] = input_seqs[1:, :]
```

I wanted to load custom data for RNN training - input vector=1, output vector =1, time_steps =1 (see attached data1a.csv). Reshape doesn't work here. Could anyone please illustrate how to do it?

```
train = pd.read_csv("data1a.csv")
input = np.array(train.values[:][:, 1:2], dtype=np.float32)
input_seqs = ???
target_seqs = ???
```

Thanks!

data link:
[links](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/--X2zGSd8rw)
[data1a.csv](https://groups.google.com/group/theano-users/attach/28565ada37494d/data1a.csv?part=0.1&authuser=0)

I'm just getting some ideas about it, but don't know how to continue:

```
train = pd.read_csv("data1a.csv")
dataset = np.array(train.values[:][:, 1:2], dtype=np.float32)

def batch(): 
    inputs = np.zeros((batch_size, time_steps, dataset.shape[1]), 'f') 
    outputs = np.zeros((batch_size, time_steps, dataset.shape[1]), 'f') 
    for b in range(batch_size): 
        i = np.random.randint(len(dataset) - time_steps - 1) 
        inputs[b] = dataset[i:i+time_steps] 
        outputs[b] = dataset[i+1:i+1+time_steps] 
    return [inputs, outputs]
```

What is the next move?

```
input_seqs = ???
target_seqs = ???
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Your data appears to contain a single sequence; Is this your full training dataset? If so, you want a 3D tensor that comprises a single batch of size 1 (i.e. num_batches=1 and batch_size=1)? Do you want both columns to be part of the input sequence? If so this would make it a 4D tensor.

Comment: In the case of data1a.csv, the input could to be structured as follows:
num_batches = 1, batch_size = 1, and num_time_steps would to be 40 numbers that come from the amounts of Newly Increased. (Not zero array in the RNN example). 
So I think it should be a 3D tensor. 

Furthermore, how to structure the input if num_batches = 2 and batch_size = 2?

Comment: num_batches > 1 and batch_size > 1 only makes sense if you have more data. If you have more data, how is it structured in the source CSV? Or do you want to to construct multiple shorter sequences from that single CSV (e.g. 2 sequences of length 20 or 4 sequences of length 10)?

Comment: I added some codes in the question. It is 1 timesteps of data to the network and predict the output at n+1 timestep. Could you shed some lights on it?

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to do. Maybe you could update your question with the actual batch structure you want to end up with, given the very limited training data you have?